# How to make a structure in React that prevents an action from passing to another action before it is completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

When I make an api request, I save the returned data in redux store, then I use this data in the route.

What I want to do is to authorize the component before installing it on the route, but I cannot authorize as the data is undefined in the route. Especially when I refresh the page it becomes undefined.

so how do I prevent the `currentUser` from rendering the `Route` before it loads?

How should I solve this problem?
Is there a tool to solve the problem?

**componentDidMount**

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actions.getCurrentUser()
  }
```

**Router**
`<Redirect to = "/" />` redirects to this because `currentUser` was initially undefined

```
<Route exact path="/profile/:id/settings" render={(props) => {
            var urlId = props.match.params.id;
        return this.props.isLogged ? this.props.currentUser.id == urlId ? < ProfileSettings {...props} /> : <Redirect to={"/profile/" + urlId} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
          }
   } />
```

**react-redux**

```
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        actions: {
          getCurrentUser: bindActionCreators(authAsyncActions.getCurrentUserApi, dispatch)
        }
      }
    }
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        isLogged: state.isLoggedReducer,
        currentUser: state.currentUserReducer,
        isOwner: state.isOwnerReducer
      }
    }
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**getCurrentUserApi**

```
export function getCurrentUserApi() {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        if (localStorageHelper.isExistsToken()) {
            if (Object.keys(getState().currentUserReducer).length == 0) {
                await axios.get(CURRENT_USER_PATH, {
                    headers: localStorageHelper.authHeaderObj()
                }).then(res => {
                    dispatch(authActionsCreators.currentUserSuccess(res.data))
                    dispatch(authActionsCreators.isLoggedTSuccess())
                }).catch(err => {
                    if (err.response.status === 401) {
                        var refreshToken = bindActionCreators(refreshTokenApi, dispatch)
                        refreshToken();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way is for the `getCurrentUserApi` action to dispatch an action that sets a loading flag and when this is set you do not forward but instead show loading. Another way is to set loading flag in local state and toggle it when current user is fetched: `this.props.actions.getCurrentUser().then(user=>set loading flag to false)`

Comment: How can I do the first way, am I going to put something like a middleWare

Comment: Before the axios call do something like; `dispatch(authActionsCreators.currentUserLoading())` and set loading to false on success and fail reducers.

Comment: I got it, thank you, I'll try this.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.